# React material ui select all checkbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to make  that when selecting checkbox **Select All**, the rest of the checkboxes from the list are checked, and each checkbox can be selected separately. But when select one of the checkboxes does not checked the previous checkbox.

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-tesla-8rboc?file=/src/App.js)

```
const options = [ 'Selected Item 1', 'Selected Item 2', 'Selected Item 3'];

export default function App() {

  const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);
  const isAllSelected = 
      options.length > 0 && selected.length === options.length;

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    console.log(value)
    if (value === "all") {
      setSelected(selected.length === options.length ? [] : options);
      return;
    }
    setSelected(value);
  };  

  const listItem = options.map((option) => {        
    return (
        <div key={option}>
          <Checkbox 
            value={option}
            onChange={handleChange} 
            checked={selected.includes(option) } />
          <span>{option}</span>
        </div>
    )
  })

  return (
    <div style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', margin: 10 }}>
        <Checkbox 
          value='all' 
          onChange={handleChange} 
          checked={isAllSelected} 
          />
        <span> Select All</span>
        {listItem}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: you want to implement multi checkbox selection right?

Comment: @RahulKumar yes absolutly

Comment: added the answer below

Answer (score 0):

Need to update `selected` options array instead of assigning the value directly inside `handleChange` method. So first check if selected list `contains the checked option` if it contains then `remove` it, otherwise `add` it to the selected list.

```
 const handleChange = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    console.log(value);
    if (value === "all") {
      setSelected(selected.length === options.length ? [] : options);
      return;
    }
    // added below code to update selected options
    const list = [...selected];
    const index = list.indexOf(value);
    index === -1 ? list.push(value) : list.splice(index, 1);
    setSelected(list);
};
```

[Sandbox link here](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-visvesvaraya-lg9b8?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

When you click on checkboxes other than "all" checkbox, you are just setting your `selected` state to that value: `setSelected(value);`. There are 2 problems with this code - 1) In your case the `selected` state should always be an array, but you are changing that to a string. 2) you are disregarding any previous values that might be added to the `selected` state. You must figure out if the clicked checkbox was already in the `selected` state or not. if not, you should add it to the state. If it was then you should remove it from the state. Here is how you can do this:

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    console.log(value)
    if (value === 'all') {
      setSelected(selected.length === options.length ? [] : options);
      return;
    }
    if (selected.indexOf(value) !== -1) { // if value already present
      const newSelected = selected.filter((s) => s !== value );
      setSelected(newSelected);
    } else { // if value not present
      setSelected([ ...selected, value ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a data-structure like `[{data:any, selected: boolean}, {data:any, selected: boolean}]`
Then you loop through it and display them as

```
  const [items, setItems] = useState<Asset[]>([]);

  const [select, setSelect] = useState(false)

  const handleChange = (index, checked) => {
   
     if(select && !checked) setSelect(false)

     const itemRef = [...items];

     itemRef[index].selected = checked

     setItems([...itemRef]);
  } 

  const handleChangeAll = (checked) => {
     const itemRef = [...items];
    
     itemRef.forEach((_item, i) => {
        itemRef[i].selected = checked

     })

     setSelect(checked)
 
     setItems([...itemRef]);
  } 

   
  ------
   All selection checkbox
 
   <Checkbox
       checked={select}
       onChange={(_e, checked) => handleChangeAll(checked)} 
      />

  ** items **
  
  items.map((item, i) => (
     <Checkbox
       key={item.data.id} 
       checked={item.selected}
       onChange={(_e, checked) => handleChange(index, checked)}  
      />

  ))
```

Once it is done if you want to extract the selected data, you can just apply the filter method based on `item.selected` from `items` array,

Answer (score 0):

Your logic for selecting all the checkboxes works quite well. As for the problem of selecting a checkbox separately you can fix this with the following code.

First we check if the `value` is already in the `selected` array, if not we can simply return a new array with the `prevSelected` and the new one. If the `value` already exists in the `prevSelected` we can remove it using the `filter` method.

```js
const handleChange = (event) => {
  const value = event.target.value;
  if (value === "all") {
    setSelected(selected.length === options.length ? [] : options);
    return;
  }
  setSelected((prevSelected) => {
    if (!prevSelected.includes(value)) return [...prevSelected, value];
    return prevSelected.filter((option) => option !== value);
  });
};
```

Little side note, it's not recommended to create your `listItem` array as a variable inside your component. As this creates a new array of checkboxes everytime your states change. You could simply map over them in your `return` statement.

```js
return (
  <div style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center", margin: 10 }}>
    <Checkbox value="all" onChange={handleChange} checked={isAllSelected} />
    <span> Select All</span>
    {options.map((option) => {
      return (
        <div key={option}>
          <Checkbox value={option} onChange={handleChange} checked={selected.includes(option)} />
          <span>{option}</span>
        </div>
      );
    })}
  </div>
);
```